# getBlob() causing "Invalid image data." Error. Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, base64, blob, google-docs

My objective is to.

1. fetch a base64 image string from a google doc
2. save it to the drive as an image
3. getblob from image and insert the new image into the same doc as a real image.

```js
function getImage(doc) {
    var tempBase64 = doc.getBody().getParagraphs()[doc.getBody().getParagraphs().length - 1].getText();
    var base64 = tempBase64.replace("data:image/svg+xml;base64,", "");
    var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(base64);
    return decoded;
}

function run() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var img = getImage(doc); //returns decoded blob
    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    //gets the name of the current doc
    var filename = DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId());
    var blobImg = Utilities.newBlob(img, MimeType.SVG, filename);
    var currentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1UuP2vZNXLVtgrZxAHLSNZUqVnx0xeSgW");
    //saves image as same name
    var newimg = currentFolder.createFile(blobImg).getId();
    //wait for image to save
    Utilities.sleep(5 * 1000);
    // get blob 
    var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(newimg).getBlob();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor();
    if (cursor) {
    //insert in to doc
        cursor.insertInlineImage(blob);
    }

}

function onOpen() {
    run();
}
```

Currently it's reading the doc and fetching the base64 string ✓
eg:

```
image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

It's saving as an image in a particular folder ✓

It's returning the id of the new image.✓

It's getting the image as a blob ✓

When it comes to inserting the image, i'm getting Invalid image data. (line 20, file "Code"). Literally no idea how to resolve. Anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your script is correct. There is only one issue. In the current stage, the images with the mimeType of `image/svg+xml` cannot be directly inserted to Google Document yet. So it is required to convert from svg image to other mimeType. In this modification, I convert to `image/png` using Drive API. Also there are several APIs, which is not Google APIs, for converting svg to others. I think that there are several workarounds in your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Modification points:

- Retrieve file ID from the created file and retrieve the thumbnailLink using Drive API.
- After the image size of the link is adjusted, retrieve the image blob of PNG.

  - It has already been found that by modifying the query parameter of `=s###`, the image size can be modified. I used this. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#principle)
- Put the PNG blob to Document.

#### Modified script:

In this modified script, `run()` was modified. Please confirm the following modified script.

```
function run() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var img = getImage(doc); //returns decoded blob
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  //gets the name of the current doc
  var filename = DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId());
  var blobImg = Utilities.newBlob(img, MimeType.SVG, filename);
  var currentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1UuP2vZNXLVtgrZxAHLSNZUqVnx0xeSgW");
  //saves image as same name
  var newimg = currentFolder.createFile(blobImg).getId();
  //wait for image to save
  Utilities.sleep(5 * 1000);
  // get blob

  // --- Added --- Begin
  var width = 300; // width of the image. A value of 300 pixels was used as a sample.
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + newimg + "?fields=thumbnailLink&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var link = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()).thumbnailLink.replace(/=s\d+/, "=s" + width);
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getBlob();
  // --- Added --- End

  var cursor = doc.getCursor();
  if (cursor) {
  //insert in to doc
      cursor.insertInlineImage(blob);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- The width and height of the svg image cannot be retrieved by Drive API. So in this modification, I used the constant width.
- I think that in your script, Drive API can be used. But if an error related to API occurs, please enable Drive API at API console.

#### Reference:

- [get method of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @AJFMEDIA Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.