# Prevent Google Drive Service API from extracting text when converting images

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I've got a script that processes files uploaded to Google Drive and if they are not pdf files it converts them into Google Docs, then converts the Google Doc file to pdf. This all works as required.

The problem I have is if the file to be converted to Google Docs is an image file, the "new" Google Docs file not only contains the image but also text extracted via OCR (I assume). I've tried setting that option to false to no avail.

Please help, all I want is to convert image files to pdf without extracting any text from the images.

```js
function afterUpload(form_upload_items, suid, lname,scans_folder){
  var pdf_file_ids, pdf_files, processed_folder, converted_file;
  form_upload_items.forEach (function (form_upload_item_id) {      
    var uploaded_file = DriveApp.getFileById(form_upload_item_id);
    const uft = uploaded_file.getMimeType();
    Logger.log("item has name of '%s' and is of type '%s'", uploaded_file.
    getName(), uft);
    processed_folder = scans_folder.getFoldersByName("Processed").next();
    var file_description = uploaded_file.getDescription();
    if (file_description==null){
      file_description=" "
    }
    if (file_description.includes("Scanned")){
      Logger.log("Already scanned '%s'", uploaded_file.getName());
    }
    else{
      uploaded_file.setDescription("Scanned");
      file_description = uploaded_file.getDescription();
    }        
    if (file_description.includes("Processed")) {
      Logger.log("Already processed %s", uploaded_file.getName());
    }
    else{
      if (uft !=MimeType.PDF && !file_description.includes("Converted")){ // convert file to pdf if required
        //Convert to Google docs
        const file_blob = uploaded_file.getBlob();
        const options ={
          ocr: false,
          supportsAllDrives: true
        }
        const res = Drive.Files.insert({ // Drive API of Advanced Google services is used.
          "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
          "title": uploaded_file.getName() + "_gdocs_conv"
        }, file_blob,options);
        uploaded_file.moveTo(processed_folder);
        uploaded_file.setDescription(file_description+", Converted");
        converted_file = DriveApp.getFileById(res.id);
        converted_file.moveTo(processed_folder);
        const blobPDF = converted_file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
        //finally convert google docs to PDF
        uploaded_file = scans_folder.createFile(blobPDF);
        Logger.log("Converted %s to pdf",uploaded_file.getName());
      }                   
    }
  });
  const query = "title contains '" +suid+"'"
  const scanned_files = scans_folder.searchFiles(query);
  pdf_file_ids = [];
  pdf_files = [];
  while (scanned_files.hasNext()){
    const scanned_file = scanned_files.next();
    Logger.log("%s %s",scanned_file.getName(), scanned_file.getDescription());
    pdf_file_ids.push(scanned_file.getId());
    pdf_files.push(scanned_file); 
  }
  var function_result = {};
  var documents_folder = scans_folder.getParents().next();
  function_result["file_name_prefix"] = suid+" "+lname;
  function_result["pdf_files"] = pdf_file_ids;
  function_result["documents_folder_id"] = documents_folder.getId(); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the file that has been created using the "Drive" service with the "DocumentApp",
2. then search the body of the DocumentApp doc for a paragraph containing the image(googledocs already resizes the image correctly).
3. Then save the paragraph to memory,
4. clear the body of the doc,
5. and lastly paste the saved paragraph back

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are converting image files into a Google Document, instead of creating a file type that could be converted into a PDF by Google Drive. To do this, insert the image to this newly created file then convert the resulting document into a PDF. Depending on the result that you requires you might create an HTML file, Google Document or a Google Slides (Google Drawings might be the best but there isn't a Google Apps Script service for that).

The "easier" solution is to create an HTML file. Here is a sample adapted from Tanaike's answer to [Show images inside a pdf created with Gloogle Apps Script Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49244622/1595451)

```
function myFunction() {
  // image
  var url = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a";
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var b64 = blob.getContentType() + ';base64,'+ Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
  var html =`<img src="data:${ b64 }">`;
  var h = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

  // Create from HTML to PDF file.
  DriveApp.createFile(h.getAs("application/pdf").setName("text.pdf"));
}
```

Related

- [getBlob() causing "Invalid image data." Error. Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54695708/1595451)

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, however I needed the function to remain as is and just either prevent ocr or remove it from final doc. I managed to do the latter. I opend the file that had been created using the "Drive" service with the "DocumentApp", then searched the body of the DocumentApp doc for a paragraph containing the image(googledocs already resizes the image correctly). Then I saved the paragraph to memory, cleared the body of the doc, then lastly I pasted the saved paragraph back.

Comment: @NoviaOneAdministration Thanks for your reply. Please consider to post your solution as answer so you can mark it as the accepted answer.